# Flutter getx package - Error: No named parameter with the name 'findProxy'

Tags: flutter, http, dart, proxy, flutter-getx

When I run the project I get an error like this, `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`  tried but no result. Thanks for read, please help..

==>
**/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.0/lib/get_connect/http/src/http.dart:60:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'findProxy'.
findProxy: findProxy,
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get-4.6.0/lib/get_connect/http/src/http/html/http_request_html.dart:13:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
HttpRequestImpl({**
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, this is caused because the package is not compatible with the current version of flutter or vice versa.

Try updating the package version from:

https://pub.dev/packages/http

Also, try importing the package using following command:

`import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

and then use functions as follows:

`http.post()`

Comment: than you  for your answer. I updated all installed packages and the problem was solved.